# How do I plug this function into the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been having some trouble with these questions, specifically with plugging the function in.
Could somebody help me with the step by step on how to plug it in and simplify? I want to get an understanding of this.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
$$\lim _{Δx\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x+Δx\right)-f\left(x\right)}{Δx}\right)$$

For the function

$$f(x)=x^2-3x+2$$

Comment: Do you know differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a more general approach for the sake of curiosity.

Let $f(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$, where $a\neq 0$. Then we have that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a[(x+h)^{2} - x^{2}] + bh}{h}\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2axh + h^{2} + bh}{h}\\\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}(2ax + b + h) = 2ax + b
\end{align*}

Such result is known as the derivative of the function $f(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$ at the point $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$f(x)=x^2-3x+2$$

$$f(a)=a^2-3a+2$$

$$f(x+b)=(x+b)^2-3(x+b)+2$$
$$=(x^2-3x+2)+b(b+2x-3)$$